# Display pdf with transparent background with pdf.js

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, background, pdf.js

I have a pdf with 4 pages, each of the page has a transparent background. I use pdf.js to display them, but I would like to display them with a transparent background on my html page but I can't figure out how I could do that, there is always a white background :

[image: example]

I think it is possible according to [this issue](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/8413#issue-229041052), but when I change the line `page.render(renderContext);` to `page.render({renderContext, viewport, backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' });` (as it said in the issue) I have the following error :

[image]

Any idea on how I could manage that ?

I use pdf.js version v1.9.426 and Firefox 55.0.2 (64 bits).

**EDIT :**
With the following code I have no error in the console but the background of my pdf file is still white. (However, If open the pdf with for example photoshop there is no background)

Link to the PDF file I use : [tempPDF.pdf](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/files/1242474/tempPDF.pdf)

Here is my javascript file to display the four pages :

```
var pdfFile;
PDFJS.getDocument('/assets/pdf/tempPDF.pdf').then(function (pdf) {
    pdfFile = pdf;

    for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'+i);
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        PDFJS.disableStream = true;
        openPage(pdf, i, context, 50);
    }
});

function openPage(pdfFile, pageNumber, context, ratio) {
    var scale = 10;
    pdfFile.getPage(pageNumber).then(function (page) {
        viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
        // reference canvas via context
        var canvas = context.canvas;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.style.width = ratio+"%";
        canvas.style.height = ratio+"%";
        var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: context
            , viewport: viewport
        };
        page.render({canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport, backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' });
        //page.render(renderContext);
    });
}
```

And my html page in case that could be useful :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body
        style="background-color:powderblue;">
</body>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="PDF Viewer" />
    <title>My page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="pdf_latex_test.php">
        <input type="submit" value="execute" /> </form>
</body>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas1" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas2" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas3" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas4" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<script src="/assets/js/pdf.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/pdf.worker.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/pdf.latex.main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Available in v1.9.426, see https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/releases/tag/v1.9.426

Comment: @async5 I tried with v1.9.426 but I have the exact the same result/error (I think I was already on v1.9.426)

Comment: please provide a complete example -- it's hard to tell if you are making an error with ES6 literal object syntax (see 'Shorthand property' example at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). It shall be `page.render({canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport, backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' });` for you.

Comment: @async5 I think the error was due to the wrong syntax, I have now no error but I still have white background. I also tried `'rgba(45,56,134,100)'` (random color) but it's also white. I edited my post with the code I use

Comment: how sure you have a transparent background in your pdf?

Comment: @async5 Well, as I said in my post, if I open the pdf in photoshop there is no background. Moreover I made my pdf using latex and `\nopagecolor` to remove any color in the background. (see [this question on tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323751/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-a-transparent-background) )

Comment: @async5 Also, in Acrobat Reader I can see the transparence (with the checkerboard option in background)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [change](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/8413/files#diff-0ecad279ed2252e3eb47a4d96ec1463cR720) and [API documentation](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js#L762) shows that property name must be `background`:

```js
var url = '//cdn.mozilla.net/pdfjs/helloworld.pdf';

PDFJS.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

var loadingTask = PDFJS.getDocument(url);
loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
  var pageNumber = 1;
  pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
    console.log('Page loaded');
    
    var scale = 1.5;
    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

    // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
    var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    // Render PDF page into canvas context
    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      // Use transparent background!
      background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
      viewport: viewport
    };
    var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
    renderTask.then(function () {
      console.log('Page rendered');
    });
  });
}, function (reason) {
  // PDF loading error
  console.error(reason);
});
```

```css
#the-canvas {
  border:1px solid black;
  background-image: url(http://image.blingee.com/images19/content/output/000/000/000/7c8/805674825_1628628.gif?6);
}
```

```html
<script src="//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
<canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Excellent. Easy find and worked like a charm <3